# quadpack.error: Supplied function does not return a valid float - when trying to double integrate over a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sympy

I have a bunch of matrices that I have to use to calculate a final 4x4 matrix [Ke] in the code shown below:

```
import numpy as num
from numpy import *
import scipy as sci
from scipy.integrate import *
from scipy import *
import sympy as sym
from sympy import *

x1 = 3; x2 = 0; x3 = 0; x4 = 3
y1 = 3; y2 = 3; y3 = 0; y4 = 0

K = []

s = symbols('s')
t = symbols('t')
k = symbols('k')

N1 = (s+1)*(t+1)/4
N2 = (1-s)*(t+1)/4
N3 = (1-s)*(1-t)/4
N4 = (s+1)*(1-t)/4

dN1s = diff(N1, s); dN1t = diff(N1, t)
dN2s = diff(N2, s); dN2t = diff(N2, t)
dN3s = diff(N3, s); dN3t = diff(N3, t)
dN4s = diff(N4, s); dN4t = diff(N4, t)

x = (x1*N1)+(x2*N2)+(x3*N3)+(x4*N4)
y = (y1*N1)+(y2*N2)+(y3*N3)+(y4*N4)

dxs = sym.diff(x, s)
dxt = sym.diff(x, t)
dys = sym.diff(y, s)
dyt = sym.diff(y, t)

print dxs, dxt, dys, dyt

J = sym.Matrix([[dxs, dys], [dxt, dyt]])
print J

J_inv = J.inv()
print J_inv

J_det = J.det()
print J_det

ST = sym.Matrix([[dN1s, dN2s, dN3s, dN4s], [dN1t, dN2t, dN3t, dN4t]])
print ST

XT = J_inv * ST
print XT

XT_trans = XT.transpose()
print XT_trans

k_small = sym.Matrix([[5, 0], [0, 5]])
print k_small

Ke = num.matrix(XT_trans*k_small*XT*J_det)
print Ke

for i in range(16):
    K.append([])
    K.append(dblquad(lambda t, s: Ke.item(i), -1, 1, lambda s: -1, lambda s: 1))

print K
```

The next step is to double integrate the matrix [Ke] with respect to 't' and 's' in the limits -1 to 1 for both. I tried looping the [Ke] matrix since scipy.integrate.dblquad doesn't have direct support for matrices. However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
quadpack.error: Supplied function does not return a valid float.
```

The problem is with the line where I try to integrate but I couldn't quite figure out what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

PS: [Ke] is always going to be a 4x4 matrix and the [k_small] is a diagonal matrix which can have any value for the diagonal.

Comment: It's a bad idea to do `import *` from multiple modules like that. SymPy, SciPy, and NumPy implement a lot of things using the same names, but as completely different functions that you can't mix and match (you can't use a numpy function on a SymPy expression or visa-versa). The way you have it, a lot of names are going to be clobbered by whichever import is last, and it will be hard to tell which functions come from which modules. It's better to do the `import as` as you have done and then reference names like `sym.integrate` and so on.

Comment: @asmeurer Thank you. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what I was doing wrong. It's more of what module I use for integration rather than the syntax. In the code in my question, I was using scipy to integrate and it didn't work. The reason was that, the integration in scipy works only if I specify the equation I'm integrating in the `dblquad` function. Since I've been trying to iterate over the matrix `Ke` and call the elements by index, I was getting an error. Now, I've modified my integration to use the `integrate` function from sympy, since this can handle a variable that calls for an equation. The modified code is given below.

```
import numpy as num
from scipy import integrate
import sympy as sym

x1 = 3; x2 = 7; x3 = 6; x4 = 3
y1 = 3; y2 = 3; y3 = 4; y4 = 5

K = []

s = sym.symbols('s')
t = sym.symbols('t')
k = sym.symbols('k')

N1 = (s+1)*(t+1)/4
N2 = (1-s)*(t+1)/4
N3 = (1-s)*(1-t)/4
N4 = (s+1)*(1-t)/4

dN1s = sym.diff(N1, s); dN1t = sym.diff(N1, t)
dN2s = sym.diff(N2, s); dN2t = sym.diff(N2, t)
dN3s = sym.diff(N3, s); dN3t = sym.diff(N3, t)
dN4s = sym.diff(N4, s); dN4t = sym.diff(N4, t)

x = (x1*N1)+(x2*N2)+(x3*N3)+(x4*N4)
y = (y1*N1)+(y2*N2)+(y3*N3)+(y4*N4)

dxs = sym.diff(x, s)
dxt = sym.diff(x, t)
dys = sym.diff(y, s)
dyt = sym.diff(y, t)

print dxs, dxt, dys, dyt

J = sym.Matrix([[dxs, dys], [dxt, dyt]])
print J

J_inv = J.inv()
print J_inv

J_det = J.det()
print J_det

ST = sym.Matrix([[dN1s, dN2s, dN3s, dN4s], [dN1t, dN2t, dN3t, dN4t]])
print ST

XT = J_inv * ST
print XT

XT_trans = XT.transpose()
print XT_trans

k_small = sym.Matrix([[k, 0], [0, k]])
print k_small

Ke = num.matrix(XT_trans*k_small*XT*J_det)
print Ke

for i in range(16):
    K.append(integrate(Ke.item(i), (t, -1, 1), (s, -1, 1)))

print K
```

Note that I've actually used the variable `k` in the matrix `k_small` and it still works (That was my actual problem, in that, the integration should be able to handle a variable in place of `k` and return an answer that is a variable by itself).